# *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated Aborted

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that allows me to enter grades for a number of students (between 1-25). For each student, I am suppose to enter a number of grades (between 1-10). For each student I am supposed to supply their first and last name, age, and grade average depending on the number of grades I enter. This is for an assignment, so I am required to have a `struct` in my program named `Info`, and inside, it has the `char` variables *firstName* and *lastName*, `int` variable *age*, and `float` variable *average*.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int gradeVar;
int studVar;       
struct Info {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    int age;
    int Exam;  //This is for something I planned to add later
    float Average;
};

int main() {
printf("How many students will you grade (1-25)? ");
     
     
    scanf("\n%i", &studVar);
    if (studVar<1 || studVar>25) {
        do{                                                
        printf("Invalid\n");                               
        printf("How many students will you grade (1-25)? ");
    scanf("\n%i", &studVar);
        } while (studVar<1 || studVar>25);
    }


printf("How many grades will you read per student (1-10)? ");       
    scanf("\n%i", &gradeVar);
    if(gradeVar<1 || gradeVar>10) {
        do{
            printf("Invalid\n");
            printf("How many grades will you read per student (1-10)? ");  
            scanf("\n%i", &gradeVar);                                      
        } while(gradeVar<1 || gradeVar>10);
    }
    
    struct Info Student[studVar];  
                                   
    for(int n=1; n <= studVar; ++n) {             
                                  
        printf("Enter First Name for student %i: ", n);
        scanf("\n%s", Student[n].firstName);
        printf("Enter Last Name for student %i: ", n);
        scanf("\n%s", Student[n].lastName);

//Every thing worked fine until I added the last two lines below//
        printf("Enter age for student %i: ", n);
        scanf("\n%d", &Student[n].age);
    };

    return 0;
}
```

It is until I add the last two lines:

```
printf("Enter age for student %i: ", n);
        scanf("\n%d", &Student[n].age);
```

That I got error in my output saying ***stacked smashing***

[image]

I am not entirely sure why this is happening, and don't know where to fix it so that it runs the way I want it to. If you anyone can clarify this for me I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have any students whose first or last name is more than 19 characters?

Comment: We need enough information the replicate the error. Does it occur with any input?

Comment: On the last iteration of the loop, `n` is equal to the length of the array, causing out of bounds writes. It should be `for(int n =0; n < studVar; ++n) {` instead.

Comment: Oh thank you, I was trying to start the number at 1 instead of 0 to indicate which student I am on.

Comment: It's great that your runtime system catches the stack overwrites! The semantics of C allow it to do anything at all in that situation. Read about Undefined Behavior, e.g. https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, when you declare `struct Info Student[studVar];`, the valid indexes for that array are zero through `studVar - 1`, ***not*** 1 through `studVar`.

Hence your `scanf` statements inside the loop should be using `n - 1` rather than `n`. Your problems is that, when you enter `2` for the number of students, that gives you `Student[0]` and `Student[1]`.

Trying to write to `Student[2].id` is going to result in undefined behaviour such as, hmmm, ..., stack smashing I guess :-)

Comment: Thank you, your explanation helped me solve it, I didn't quite do exactly what you told me, but I got it to work by just adding n+1 in my printf and scanf statements.

Answer (score 2):

Expected:

```
for(int n=0; n < studVar; ++n)
```

Got:

```
for(int n=1; n <= studVar; ++n)
```

Arrays are 0 based not 1 based.

There's another overflow waiting for you if you exceed 19 characters in a name component.